# shutting down with code:62 in mongodb localhost?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm beginner in Mongodb.Im using mongo version **4.0.2**. I have been working in mongodb Past few days.past two three days It has been worked fine.suddenly my system updated.After that I could not run mongodb in localhost.

If i execute **mongod** **in cmd.**I have gotten **" shutting down with code:62"** [image]
**If I execute mongo in cmd.**It shows **connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed**.I have attached the pic .Anyone can resolve this problem.Thanks in advance...
[image]

Comment: May be the case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312358/mongo-couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017/53635485#53635485

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongo - couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312358/mongo-couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017)

Answer (score 1):

Go in the main c:/ drive and check if the folder exists with the name of **data** if not

- Go to root directory that is c:/  in case of windows
- create folder with name data
- Go inside data folder and create new folder db

Hope it would solve your error and let me know if not

Comment: Yes now it's working.Already I had that folder.I have deleted the folder and created from first now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had already data folder in c drive.It contains db and log folder.Even though I have faced the error .I could not run mongoDB in Localhost.I have faced the error What I have mentioned above.I tried...

step-1:
   I have **uninstalled mongoDB version 4.0.2**

step-2:
   I have **deleted the data folder in cdrive  and taken backup in some other location**.

step-3:
  Again I have **installed mongoDB version 4.0.2**

step-4:
  I have **copied the folder which I have taken backup previously in the same location c drive**

Now problem is solved Everything working fine. Actually we have faced this problem because of system update.

Note: This is also **one of the solution**.For me its working fine.
Thank you All...