# Cannot start mongod DV server

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

Hello i have tried to write simple .sh bash script to start mongodb and connect my app to local mongoDB but receiving following error:   `exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating`

after typing `mongod`. 
Do you have any guess what kind of error it is?

Comment: The error, as shown, means you don't have a data directory at `/data/db` - have you verified that the directory exists and that `mongod` has access rights to it?

Comment: solved it like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312358/mongo-couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017systemctl start mongod
systemctl enable mongod.

Answer (score 0):

Create the /data/db folder and define it on mongod.cfg file.....you should also check

[What is the default database path for MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738322/what-is-the-default-database-path-for-mongodb)